# Convert nested for loops to list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have to convert nested for loops to list comprehension:

```
H = cvxopt.matrix(0.0, (rows, rows), tc='d')

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(rows):
        H[i, j] = t[i] * t[j] * kf(X[i], X[j], param)
```

I have tried this:

```
H = [t[i] * t[j] * kf(X[i], X[j], param) for H[i, j] in H]
```

But this is giving me an error `i` not defined.

Comment: I don't think you can use a list comprehension to build a `cvxopt.matrix`.

Comment: You could build a list with `H = [t[i] * t[j] * kf(X[i], X[j], param) for i in range(rows) for j in range(rows)]`, but it's not going to do the same thing as your `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot build a matrix exactly from a list comprehension, only `list`s. Thats just because Python has no built-in matrix type.

You *can* build the next best thing, a `list` of `list`s. E.g.

```
>>> [[i + 3 * j for i in range(N)] for j in range(N)]
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
```

Then you can use the [`cvxopt.matrix`](https://cvxopt.org/examples/tutorial/creating-matrices.html) constructor to convert to a `matrix`.

```
H = cvxopt.matrix([[i + 3 * j for i in range(N)] for j in range(N)])
```

In your example, with `t` being defined somewhere (thats not included in the question), you could do:

```
H = cvxopt.matrix([[t[i] * t[j] * kf(X[i], X[j], param) for i in range(rows)] for j in range(rows)])
```